# Trying to read a file - python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code (on python) that will read a file with a list of products, a GTIN-8 code for each, a description, stock and price for each individual product.

So far I managed to read the top line, printing out its details, but I am unsure how to read the next line down. Any Help? Please try and keep it simple :)

PP

Code for my man Doroskevic:

```
#csv is imported to read/write to the file
import csv

#Each Product is printed alongside it's GTIN-8 code and Price
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print("~ Welcome to Toms bits and bobs ~")
print("Pencil,          12346554, £0.40")
print("50 Staples,      12346882, £1.00")
print("50 Paper Clips,  12346875, £1.20")
print("Large Eraser,    12346844, £1.50")
print("100 A4 Sheets,   12346868, £2.00")
print("100 A3 Sheets,   12346837, £2.50")
print("25 Byro Pens,    12346820, £2.20")
print("Handwriting Pen, 12346899, £5.50")
print("50 Split Pins,   12346813, £0.60")
print("Office Chair,    12346912, £25.00")
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")

#The file is opened and the user inputs the code for the product they
#wish to find.
file = open("Product_list.csv", "r")
purchase = input(print("Please enter the GTIN-8 code of the product you wish to purchase e.g 12346554"))
line = file.readline()
data = line.split(",")
if purchase == "12346554":
    while(line):
        print ("Product: ", data[0])
        print ("GTIN-8 code: ", data[1])
        print ("Stock: ", data[2])
        print ("Description: ", data[3])
        print ("Price: ", data[4])
        line = file.readline()
        break
if purchase == "12346882":
    while(line):
        print ("Product: ", data[0])
        print ("GTIN-8 code: ", data[1])
        print ("Stock: ", data[2])
        print ("Description: ", data[3])
        print ("Price: ", data[4])
        line = file.readline()
        break

file.close()
```

Comment: hi, could you show your code?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Example:**

```
path = 'c:/users/-e/my documents/text.txt'

with open(path, 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

    for line in data:
        print(line, end='')
```

**Output:**

```
Are all the good times dead and gone?
Come and go and come and go (come and come and go)
I got a lot of friends who are stars
But some are just black holes

By Fall out boy - 27
```

Function `.readlines()` will read all lines within file into a `list` structure. This will allow further operations to be carried out as needed.

**Reference:**

[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)
[Python TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

Comment: Could you please provide a link to where this polcy is described? If no link is provided, is the quality of the above answer not satisfactory? If yes, could you also provide a link to the criteria? Else - I would appreciate if you would remove the down-vote.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation (im new :D) gave it a tick though

Comment: apologise I find the page hard to understand

Comment: @E.Doroskevic It is pretty much all over meta. 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: @Altoyr can you please stop mentioning the duplicate, it doesn't matter that there is another question on this website, just ignore it if you want to. You referred me to another question and I thank you for doing so.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic See http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates . See the part about *"search and research"* in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . See the part about *"Please look around to see if your question has been asked before"* in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @AdrianHHH that's cool, where does it state that people should be down-voted for providing answers to duplicate questions? I think this should be taken into a chat for a broader discussion

Comment: @E.Doroskevic Already discussed at great length. See the answers to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions and its duplicates.